# How to use 'depends_on' with 'for_each' in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've got a terraform plan that creates a number of resources in a `for_each` loop, and I need another resource to `depend_on` those first ones. How can I do it without having to explicitly list them?

Here's the first resource (AWS API Gateway resource):

```json
locals {
  apps = toset(["app1", "app2", "app3"])
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
  for_each                = local.apps 
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.primary.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.lambda[each.key].id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.lambda_post[each.key].http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.lambda[each.key].invoke_arn
}
```

Now I need to wait for all the 3 apps integrations before creating an API Gateway deployment:

```json
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "primary" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.primary.id

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda["app1"],
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda["app2"],
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda["app3"],
  ]
```

However the list of apps keeps growing and I don't want to maintain it manually over here. Everywhere else I can simply use `for` or `for_each` together with `local.apps` but I can't figure out how to dynamically build the list for `depends_on`? Any ideas?

Comment: You can't build depends_on dynamically and this resource type appears to have a work around for that. See the note about depends_on and triggers in the [api_gateway_deployment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_deployment) docs

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies in Terraform are always between static blocks (`resource`, `data`, and `module` blocks mainly) and *not* between individual instances of those objects.

Therefore listing individual instances like you did in your example is redundant:

```
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda["app1"],
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda["app2"],
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda["app3"],
  ]
```

The above is exactly equivalent to declaring a dependency on the resource as a whole:

```
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda,
  ]
```

The `for_each` argument itself typically has its own dependencies (e.g. `local.apps` in your example) and so Terraform needs to construct the dependency graph *before* evaluating `for_each`. This means that there is only one node in the dependency graph representing the entire resource (including its `for_each` expression), and the individual instances are not represented in the plan-time dependency graph at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually. [TF docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) clearly explain that depends_on must be explicitly defined:

> You only need to **explicitly specify a dependency**

Answer (score 0):

There is another way:

- Create a module with for_each approach called **aws_api_gateway_integration**
- Modify module to support all parameters needed
- Then you can just call new objects to create - example[image]
- At the end you can put depends_on on a module -   **depends_on = [
  module.logic_app
  ]**